# Javascript Form submission: undefined

Tags: javascript

This must be a simple problem but i can't figure out why it's not working. The script shall pass values of the `tags` field to a script on the same page.

```
<FORM id="form" METHOD="" ACTION="#" >
<input size="40" name='tags' id='tags' onSubmit="javascript: submitForm(this)">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" id='q' VALUE="Submit" >
<INPUT TYPE="reset" VALUE="Reset">
</FORM>
<div id='info'>This sentence will be replaced</div>

<script>

var tags;

function submitForm(form)
{
    tags = form.tags.value
    return false ;
}
alert(tags)
...
</script>
```

alert box says: `undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You run that alert before running `submitForm()`. Try moving `alert(tags)` before `return false;`, inside `submitForm(form)`.

```
function submitForm(form)
{
 tags = form.tags.value;
 alert(tags);
 return false ;
}
```

Comment: the alert is not coming up when i try that. bw, in my posted code it was added it after to see if i can access the variable outside the function

Comment: some progress: if i move the call into the submit button line and change it to 'onclick' i get an alert. However it says: [Object HTMLInputElement]...getting closer!